# How to make animated 3D scatter plot in plotly

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, data-visualization, slice

My goal is to create an animation with my 3D data in plotly.
I have 3 variables x,y,z for simplicity and I plot the 4th value depending on these x,y,z.
I create a 3D scatter plot where the 4th dim sort to speak is the color like this:

```py
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers.default = 'notebook'
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import math

import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("paramtp_1e-05_big.txt") 
data.head()
data = data.iloc[::10, :]

color_data = data['gopt'].astype(float).round(decimals=2)
color_data[color_data>= 10] = 10
color_data_nopt = data['nopt'].astype(float).round(decimals=3)
color_data_mc = data['mc'].astype(float).round(decimals=3)
color_data_P= data['P']
color_data_P[color_data_P >= 1] = 1


data= data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
data.tail()

fig = px.scatter_3d(data, x='NpN0', y='s', z='mu',log_x=True, log_z=True,
              opacity = 0.5,      
              color=color_data,color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=1,
            opacity=0.5,
            
        ),
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Similarly to this wonderful animation: https://plotly.com/python/visualizing-mri-volume-slices/
I would like to slice up my data to isosurfaces with respect to any x,y,z coordinates.

As in the example they use images, I could not wrap my head around to create the same with my raw data.

Thank you in advance.